# SUMIF or INDEX - finding sum that meets date within date range

Tags: excel

This seems like it should be pretty simple. I am trying to get the sum of values for everyday in a given month.

I would like the formula in K2 to find the sum of all quantities when the City is Houston and 9/1 is found between the start and end date range in columns E and F. So forth and so on..  I'm just not sure if I could do a SUMIF for multiple criteria with matching the city and then the date being found in the same date range.

Hope this is possible -- thank you!

[image: Excel Pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use SUMIFS()

```
=SUMIFS($D:$D,$C:$C,SUBSTITUTE(K$1," Total",""),$E:$E,"<=" & $J2,$F:$F,">=" & $J2)
```

[image]

Comment: @hb45 When the question is 15 minutes old, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.